# ReactNative AnimatedComponent: null is not at object ('evaluating transform.forEach)

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist, react-animated

Im implementing a DraggablFlatlist/ Flatlist in my react native project.
That component uses react reanimated. When i run the simulator on Ios it runs fluently, however the second i switch over to android, this error occur "null is not an object"
[image]

my packages

```
react-native-draggable-flatlist: ^2.6.1,
react-native-reanimated: ^2.0.0,
react-native: 0.63.2,
react: 16.13.1,
expo: 4.4.3
```

Error prompt terminal:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'transform.forEach')

This error is located at:
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at ListView.js:57)
    in RowItem (created by CellRenderer)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:441)
    in AnimatedComponent(View) (at createAnimatedComponent.js:452)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:441)
    in AnimatedComponent(View) (at createAnimatedComponent.js:452)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:441)
    in AnimatedComponent(View) (at createAnimatedComponent.js:452)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper)
    in Unknown (at VirtualizedList.js:2127)
    in CellRenderer (at VirtualizedList.js:900)
```

Does anyone know why this problem only affects android in expo and not IOS.
And is this due to react-native-reanimated not being fully compatible with the android sdk? The problem is valid for both android phone and simulator.

Comment: Did you follow Android instructions?

Comment: [https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/installation/](React-native-reanimated). Partly, but i don't have the files: android/app/build.gradle or MainApplication.java as pointed out in the guide. My app structure is the following: `-App
--expo 
--.vscode
--assets
--node_modules
--src
---assets
---components
---constants
---navigation
---redux
---screens
--App.js
--app.json 
--package.json`

Comment: is it an expo project?

Comment: @LeriGogsadze yes it is